# Client can't target spring method

Tags: java, spring, annotations

My client fails to "target" a method, I don't get feedback in server log. Which is very weird to me.

My method is defined as follows:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/reUploadFile/{userId}/{fileId}", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Accept=*")
    public @ResponseBody()
    void reUploadFile(@PathVariable("userId") int userId, @PathVariable("fileId") int fileId,
            @RequestParam(value = "file") MultipartFile multipartFile,
            Model model, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

    ...Stuff happends doesn't get called
    }
```

It's almost identic to the folow method which works:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadFile/{companiesId}/{day}/{month}/{year}/{userId}",
    method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Accept=*")
    public void uploadFile(@PathVariable("companiesId") long companiesId,
            @PathVariable("day") int day, @PathVariable("month") int month,
            @PathVariable("year") int year, @PathVariable("userId") int userId,
            @RequestParam(value = "file") MultipartFile multipartFile,
            Model model, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
     ...content
    }
```

My network manager in chrome looks like this:
The failed:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:8080/MyProject.spring/spring/reUploadFile/3821211/154329
Request Method:POST
Status Code:500 Internal Server Error
```

The successful:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:8080/MyProject.spring/spring/uploadFile/25974093/01/06/2013/3821211
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
```

Can anyone figure out why I get error 500 here?
If you need additional information just holla and i'll get it to you :)
Thanks for reading :)

Comment: Try removing `@ResponseBody()` from `reUploadFile`, that seems to be the only difference.
If you are keen to keep that, then please post the exception form the server.

Comment: can you post a error log

Comment: @SanjayaLiyanage I don't get feedback in server log. so that kind of means no error log neither. Else thanks :)

Comment: @BalintBako ResponseBody will not cause errors although you put it for void

Comment: Are you sure that you are not handling the error within the uploadFile method?

Comment: I'm not even getting into the beginning of it when debugging

Comment: And All my try catch' has this to ensure logging: java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(HomeController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Status Code:500 Internal Server Error means something is wrong in your logic inside reUploadFile method. It can find the end point(url) with no issue, Check whether any exception is thrown inside your logic. I guess multipartFile has not set properly .

Comment: No it aparently does not, I have debugged, and tried to stop in the very first line. And it never gets to that point

Comment: Then issue must be in here "@RequestParam(value = "file") MultipartFile multipartFile" .Just test by setting this parameter required false or temporary remove this part and test.

Answer (score 0):

You no need to provide @ResponseBody() as your response type is void. So remove and try again

Comment: @ResponseBody will not cause errors although you put it for void.Hense -1 from me